# wso2am store - Trying to hide the carbon.super tenant

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to set up a multi tenant installation of wso2am.
i have created some new tenants and when  visit the public store site, i can see all tenants, including the carbon.super.

Is it possible to hide the super.carbon tenant store?

Comment: Public store will display all the stores of active tenants. There is no way to deactivate carbon super tenant. What you can do is you can avoid displaying the super.carbon tenant store by modifying the store app. However accessing the url of super tenant store will give pages related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hide carbon.super tenant domain please follow the instructions below.

in template.jag(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/api/tenant-stores-listing/template.jag) paste following before this line

```
<%for(var i=0;i< tenantDomains.length;i++){
if(tenantDomains[i] != "carbon.super"){
var site = require("/site/conf/site.json");
%>
<a href="<%= encode.forHtmlAttribute(encode.forUri(jagg.getSiteContext() + 
"?tenant="+tenantDomains[i])) %>" title="<%=tenantDomains[i]%>">
<li class="thumbnail span3 tenent-thumb">
<center><img src="<%=jagg.getAbsoluteUrl(jagg.getThemeFile("images/tenant-store.png"))%>" alt="">
<h3><%=tenantDomains[i]%></h3>
<span>Visit Store</span>
</center></a></li><%}}%>
```

Then it will filter out carbon.super from main store view. You can do this change using sub theme and override default page. To do that please follow this [article about API Manager sub themes](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-add-sub-theme-to-api-manager.html).

Comment: I will try it and report the results asap